# Remove bloatware from a Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung, bloatware

I just bought a Samsung Galaxy S4 and I'd like to get rid of a lot of applications I found installed but I'm not going to use.

What options do I have?

Surfing the web it seems that I cannot do it without rooting and the only option I have is to [disable the applications I don't want](http://www.businessinsider.com/remove-bloatware-on-samsung-galaxy-s4-2013-5). Is that the only option?

Alternatively I saw that a lot of web site links to [TrulyClean](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2307355) but it seems to be discontinued.
Is there any alternative script I should look for?

I see that there is the possibility to install other ROMs ([Maybe the one that Google uses for the version of the device it sells on the play store](http://www.technobuffalo.com/videos/how-to-turn-a-galaxy-s4-into-a-google-edition-phone/)). Would that help me getting rid of all the bloatware?

These were the options I found searching the web, would you recommend me to go down for any of these three paths or is there any better option?
I'd like to know which are the pros and cons of each of them so that I can come up with the best decision for my needs.

Comment: Looks like you've just used the `bloatware` tag without having looked into [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/bloatware/info) :) Please check it, the answers are already there. And yes: without rooting all you can do is to disable unwanted apps.

Comment: @Izzy thanks, I was not aware of the presence of tag-wiki pages. Now I read the linked Q&As but I am still not sure about know which approach is the best.

Comment: Tag Wikis are always a good place to look at first. Many of them contain first aid on problems and links to related questions. Second, the tags "most frequented" questions are helpful as well, and our search engine is excellent. Anyhow, if "disabling" is not enough for you (or doesn't work on some of the apps), rooting is the first step in any case. After that, you can check if you go for bloatware-removers or rather a custom ROM.

Answer (score 2):

DjeMBeY has created a [custom ROM on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2250824) which contains stock ROM, minus the bloatware. It is pre-rooted; once you flash it, you also get root. There is also a Google Play edition if that's what you want.